# Are multiple environments required for Business Glossary?

Tags: project-management, terminology

I have a situation where I need to make a decision between choosing multiple environments or sticking to one. The Business wants to use multiple, but it is simple glossary (list of terms and definitions) which we link to our development tools. Considering the fact that it is simple glossary and not code development, I don't see any reason, why we need to have multiple environments. Also, another drawback with multiple environments is some migration processes between the environments is not automated and must be done manually with every release. Can anyone point me to relevant resources or explain me one convincing reason to explain to the Business?. I appreciate your time and help.

Thank you

Comment: The desire to have multiple environments is typically not because of functional differences but rather to address organizational requirements like responsibilities and quality insurance and being able to freeze a status so it can be tested. It seems you are ignoring or missing the point of having multiple environments. What does "the business" have to say about it, why do they want it?

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, multiple environments are necessary.

The business is absolutely correct in wanting multiple environments.  You should consider yourself fortunate that you have management that understands the necessity of completely separating your dev environment from production.

This gives you the opportunity to load up the Glossary with as much test data (including strange end cases) as you'd like.  It also means the business won't be dictating which data you may have and which you may not.

If your manual release process is so messed up that you cannot support multiple environments, then you'd best fix that process as soon as you can before something terrible happens.

Comment: Thank you Dan. Yes, the release is kind of messed up. It involves manually assigning each terms to their respective stewards and there is no turnaround. Will figure out if this can be fixed. I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I've found that even if you don't think you need multiple environments, you do.  Even for simple static data like this.  What happens when you want to change some glossary terms as part of a long running project?  If you only have one environment, those changes are in prod too and you probably don't want that.

I would say you at least need a prod and non-prod enviornment.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff. Appreciate your time. I like this approach.

Comment: No problem, good luck!